# How do I delete old nodes (with attachments) after running cron?

Tags: 8, cron

I've site on Drupal 8.1.x with many nodes (over 200). That node type is **articles**. Some nodes are old (written last year, for example) and have non actuality content with attach files (photos).

How to make easy way to delete old (older than **30 days** from today) nodes of one type (name **articles**) with all attachments (photos) after run Drupal Cron (for example, time to run Cron is every week)?

Write custom module or use [`hook_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/function/hook_cron/8.1.x) or something else?

Any working examples helps me to understand. Thanks!

Comment: A custom module with a hook_cron implementation would be the easiest, yes. I couldn't think of site-building recipe to do this in D8.